# How to apply boolean_mask to a onehot vector in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have my vector `y`, and I also know the useful lengths of y, `len_y`. I also have `onehot_y = tf.one_hot(y, n_classes)` which is the onehot representation of `y`.

I have already created a mask of len_y.

This is an example with batchsize = 2

```
mask_y = tf.sequence_mask(len_y)
mask_y = [[True True    True    True    True    True    True    True    True],
          [True True    True    True    True    False   False   False   False]]
```

So, from my first element, only the 9th first values are useful, and from the second one only the 5th first values are usefull.

If apply this mask to `y` like `tf.boolean_mask(y,mask_y)` I get the results as expected, but I don't know how to apply this to `onehot_y`, it doesn't complain but gives me extrange results.

This is what I'm getting (converted to numerical representation instead on onehot for simplicity):

```
y = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
     [1,11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91]]

y_oh_true = tf.boolean_mask(onehot_y, mask_y)

y_oh_true = onehot_of ->[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,11,21,31]
```

Where I would expect:

```
y_oh_true = onehot_of ->[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,11,21,31,41]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the shape of y_oh_true be 2-D?

Comment: Yes, it's 2d but I thought that would be too long and hard to visualize, that's why I put it that way

Comment: @SergeiLebedev I edited to make it more clear

Comment: Could you also explain why you expect TF *not* to take 9 from the first sequence?

Comment: Because the first row of mask_y has 9 "Trues", so I expect tf to take the first 9 elements->from 0 to 8

Comment: I'm actually surprised this does fail because the last dimension of y should exactly match that of mask. Whereas in your example y is 2x10 whereas the mask 2x9.

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved, I had to specify maxlen when doing `tf.sequence_mask`

In my case, to fix it it's just:
 `mask_y = tf.sequence_mask(self.len_y, maxlen=tf.shape(self.y)[1])`.

What it is not clear to me is why `tf.boolean_mask` doesn't complain if shapes don't fit instead of doing this weird thing.

Comment: Which version of TF are you using? 1.12 does complain.

Comment: I'm using tf 1.11